# I can't make these few simple line of code work correctly and have no idea why

Tags: javascript

I tried to this simple exercise , i did get it to work but not correctly. It's supposed to give you a random number between 0 and 1000 as you click a button. When you click the button again , it creates another random number , if its bigger than the last one , it displays it. If it is not , it does nothing. And while it does this , it counts how many times it had run the function.
The one i made did give me random numbers but sometimes , it displayed smaller numbers than the last one and sometimes it didn't. I can't figure out why. I suspect it might be because of the line of code where i tried to change what the button does.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<input id="btn" type="button" onclick="initiate(1)" value="Click me!"><br>
<script>
function geid(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
var count = 0;

function initiate(n) {
    var x = n;
    n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function () {
        initiate(n);
    }

    if (n > x) {
        geid("fid").innerHTML = n;
        count += 1;
        geid("fid2").innerHTML = count + " times";

    } else {
        count += 1;
        geid("fid2").innerHTML = count + " times";

    }
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
Number : <div id="fid">0</div>
Tried <div id="fid2">0</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you're gonna have to edit your code. It seems you left it **ALL** inside the head T_T

Comment: What error do you see in the console?

Comment: Move your `<input />` tag down into between the `<body>` and `</body>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're always changing the `onclick` function, regardless of whether the newly chosen `n` value is greater than the previous value (`x`) or not.

Take this example: suppose that the statement  `Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);` produces this sequence of values when you run it multiple times: 100, 500, 200, 300.

With the first click, the function was called as `initiate(1)`, the spot `fid1` was set to hold `100`, and the onclick handler was set to call `initiate(100)`.

With the second click, the function was called as `initiate(100)`, the spot `fid1` was set to hold `500`, and the onclick handler was set to call `initiate(500)`. So far so good.

With the third click, the function was called as `initiate(500)`, the spot `fid1` was left unchanged at `500`, and the onclick handler was set to call `initiate(200)`. Um...

With the fourth click, the function was called as `initiate(200)`, the spot `fid1` was set to hold `300`, and the onclick handler was set to call `initiate(300)`.

So the issue is that if you want to change the handler to hold always the current value in `fid1`, then you shouldn't change the handler unless `n > x`.

Comment: Though my answer explains what's wrong with the initial solution, other answers that make it so that you aren't changing the `onclick` handler all the time, but instead hold the fid1 value in a separate global variable, are better style over all.

Comment: I like your elaborate answer. The question is: does the author actually know what a handler is, how it works, how javascript is different from other languages... etc

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be several errors in here of how things are placed.  This rearrangement should work:

```
function geid(id){return document.getElementById(id);}
var count = 0;
    var x = 0;

function initiate(){
    n =  Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);

    if(n>x){
        x = n;
        geid("fid").innerHTML = n;
        count +=1;
        geid("fid2").innerHTML = count + " times";

    }else{
        count +=1;
        geid("fid2").innerHTML = count + " times";
    }
}

document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function(){
    initiate();
}
```

There is plenty of room for optimization, but this should be pretty clear.

---

### Update

Here is a version that I think is relatively clean:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Click me!"><br>
<p>Number : <span id="number">0</span></p>
<p>Tried <span id="tried">0</span></p>
<script>
    function geid(id){return document.getElementById(id);}
    var count = 0, highest = 0, number = geid("number"), tried = geid("tried");

    geid("btn").onclick = function(){
        var random =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
        count += 1;
        tried.innerHTML = count + " times";

        if (random > highest){
            highest = random;
            number.innerHTML = random;
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would still probably wrap the whole thing in an IIFE in order to not expose anything on the global scope, but other than that, this code is now reasonably readable, and reasonably efficient, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

here's a clean version

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      (function(){
        var count = 0, lastRandom = 0, click;
        click = function () {
          var random;
          random = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
          if (random > lastRandom) {
            document.getElementById("fid").innerHTML = random;
          }
          count += 1;
          document.getElementById("fid2").innerHTML = count+" times";
        };
        window.addEventListener('load',function(){
          document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',click,false);
        },false);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="Click me!"><br>
    Number : <div id="fid">0</div>
    Tried <div id="fid2">0</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Don't just copy paste this. If it works (I can't test it right now), then try to understand what it's doing. If you can't then please ask, I can add some comments if you need them

Answer (score 0):

If you click the button really fast this change won't take effect....

```
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function(){ // right here
  initiate(n);                                       // so not a good idea.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put this:

```
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function(){
    initiate(n);
}
```

Outside your initiate function

like:

```
function geid(id){return document.getElementById(id);}
var count = 0;

function initiate(n){
    var x = n;
    n =  Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);


if(n>x){
    geid("fid").innerHTML = n;
    count +=1;
    geid("fid2").innerHTML = count + " times";

}else{
    count +=1;
    geid("fid2").innerHTML = count + " times";

}


}

window.onload = function() {



    document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function(){
      var n = 10; // some number    
      initiate(n);
    }
}
```